# How to set Xcode 4.3 to not start the simulator when "UnitTesting"?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4, ios-simulator, settings

Is there a way to tell Xcode (4.3) not to start the simulator while Running or Testing my Application? It is kind of annoying and seems to like a time eater, when one only wants to know if the tests pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently it is not possible to deactivate the Simulator because it is needed for unittesting.